# Sushi Salmon left uncovered overnight in fridge safe to eat?

Tags: food-safety, fish, sushi, safety

I thawed raw sushi salmon the day before and then wrapped it in papertowels and put it in the fridge overnight, but I forgot to put a lid on the container.
It the salmon still safe to eat? Since the papertowels were also a lil wet due to the frozen salmon leaking some juices.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing you've identified that would make it unsafe.  As long as you've kept it below 40F (4.5C) you are good.  Covering is not a critical issue for safety, temperature is.